# Should I use different services for a different area in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So, I am using a classic MVC architecture with a service layer for my ASP.NET core app.
I added an `Admin` area and in it I added `Controllers`, `Models` and `Views` folders, so I can easily separate the admin-related stuff from the general user-related stuff. Now I have two options:

1. Creating a `Services` folder in my `Admin` area and literaly copy-pasting the already created services, but from my general `Services` folder
2. Directly using the already created services from the general `Services` folder

I am not sure which approach is generally accepted as better, so I hope for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use it as is, then the general Service folder is enough, but if you need to change/add many things than it is a good idea to create a separate service. (You can still use the general Service as a dependency in your admin service)